# Laravel Route List (php artisan route:list) Displaying Middleware on New Lines

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have noticed recently a change in the way that my Laravel project is rendering the route list in the terminal. It is no longer comma separating the middleware column, and if there is more than one middleware it will add it to a new blank row in the table underneath its parent route.

This may seem like a very trivial problem, however being relatively new to laravel and this being my first proper project I have been producing with it I am firstly concerned that there could be an issue with the laravel install somehow that may cause other issues elsewhere, and the more routes I add with various middleware, the table when displaying all routes is becoming rather difficult to interoperate, where this was not an issue before.

See below a screenshot of the route table filtered to show only a select number of the routes in my project in order to give you an idea of what I am seeing.

[image: Route table]

Would anyone know why this has changed, and if there is a way to get it back to displaying it as it was before, by keeping all the middleware on the row with all the other data, and comma separating them.

On a whim, I have tried the following in the console, and they have made no difference:

`php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan routes:clear`
`php artisan config:clear`

To be clear, what I expect to see is something like this:

[image: Route table]

Comment: Cannot reproduce (on Linux). Any package installed that might change it? Which shell/terminal are you using?

Comment: I am using macOS for development, I did previously see it the correct way, was only recently it changed to display as above. This error is replicated on both my macOS machine (for development) and on the Linux Ubuntu server I am using for production. I am unsure if there have been any package installs that would have made that change, could you suggest a way to try and find out?

Comment: I doubt that this fixes it but you could try `php artisan route:list --no-ansi` (for me output was just uncolored). Install a fresh vanilla Laravel 7 project somewhere without any additional packages and see if the problem persists. Other than that, no clue, sorry. (What version of Laravel7 exactly are you using?)

Comment: By color of header it seems to be output from different terminals/consoles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have since been informed that Laravel updated this a few days ago in their framework:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32993

It was as a result of this issue being raised:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/33041

Comment: Fwiw, Laravel 9 – `php artisan route:list -v` for "verbose" will print middleware.

Answer (score 2):

**If** you want to add semicolon again

Go to your project file vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console
then open file RouteListCommand.php

search for function `getMiddleware`

```
protected function getMiddleware($route)
    {
        return collect($this->router->gatherRouteMiddleware($route))->map(function ($middleware) {
            return $middleware instanceof Closure ? 'Closure' : $middleware;
        })->implode("\n");
    }
```

just change `\n` to `,` in `implode`

Answer (score 0):

I added a cross-platform one-liner workaround that prints one row per route to the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/33041#issuecomment-1309681356) (more details there):

```bash
php artisan route:list | perl -pe 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mG]//g' | perl -0777 -pe 's/ +\|(\r\n?|\n)/\n/g' | perl -0777 -pe 's/(\r\n?|\n)(\| +){6}/, /g'
```

Breakdown:

```bash
# strip control characters: https://superuser.com/a/561105
# strip trailing whitespace and pipe character, substituting newline with \0 during processing via -0
# strip leading pipes and whitespace before middleware column, substituting newline with \0 during processing via -0
php artisan route:list | \
perl -pe 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mG]//g' | \
perl -0pe 's/ +\|(\r\n?|\n)/\n/g' | \
perl -0pe 's/(\r\n?|\n)(\| +){6}/, /g'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the fix, if you are still facing issues in Laravel 8 with Sanctum.

I have replacedon this line

```
return collect($this->router->gatherRouteMiddleware($route))->map
```

with this line on

```
return collect($route->gatherMiddleware())->map
```

in Laravel's core file. Usually, this is not recommended, but I need a solution. You can also try if needed.

For more details, please visit the below link and refer to my comment on this page.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/7ebd21193df520d78269d7abd740537a2fae889e